# How can I solidify magazine for an AK-47?

Tags: modeling, solidify-modifier

I've modelled a magazine for an AK-47 however I am having problems with solidifying it because of its curved nature. Solidify modifier does not work as well as I'd want it too because of the complexity of the object. I've tried duplicating faces etc and none of it works. What could I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: with some topologies it won't work fine and you need to correct manually, or do it manually, do you really need to give it thickness?

Comment: @Jameson4279 Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: In this case it does require thickness as the AK I have modelled features interior parts too. @moonboots

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solidify modifier and had no issue.

Here is the file.
[image]

Can you clarify where exactly you're not happy with the result?

[image]

Comment: It does infact work roughly as intended however it creates a myriad of geo problems that would be really annoying to fix.

Comment: Happy to try to help if you can screenshot one of these problems.